How to configure HSTS on Couch DB when it's packaged with another app?
I have this very large and complex server application that amongst the numerous opensource tools that are baked into it, CouchDB 3.3.3 is one of them. "Baked" is important because what the vendor does is bake a stripped-down version of Couch it's not a full install. As part of our application deployment all installs have to get security scanned and the security folks are bent out of shape over the port that Couch is configured on (29081 in this case, set in stone by the vendor of the app) not returning "Strict-Transport-Security" in the header. This app also includes Apache (which we are able to harden) and some of the traffic goes through Apache to Couch via that port hence the https part of this. Here's the problem: I can access Couch via:
CURL>curl -X GET -u admin:password https://someserver:29081/_users

and even see that the databases exist:
CURL>curl -X GET -u admin:password https://someserver:29081/_all_dbs
["_replicator","_users","dsconfig$"]

But when I try
CURL>curl -X GET -u admin:password https://someserver:29081/settings/security/responseHeaders
Per https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/rest-api/rest-setting-hsts.html I get
{"error":"not_found","reason":"Database does not exist."}

I'm also able to get to the Fauxton web interface but there appears to be no HSTS configuration section/setting that is obvious.


and some of the traffic goes through Apache to Couch via that port hence the https part of this

could force-add the header on every apache response under VirtualHost, eg
<VirtualHost *:443>
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"


"Baked" is important because what the vendor does is bake a stripped-down version of Couch it's not a full install

Best guess, the stripped-down db simply doesn't support the settings/security/responseHeaders endpoint. Luckily you can probably add the HSTS headers with Apache instead.

We've already got Apache configured for Strict-Transport-Security. Problem is any calls to the CouchDB port appear to bypass that.

@tpcolson hmm.. maybe configure apache to proxy all requests to CouchDB?

We thought of that to. The way the app is using Couch, we can't tinker with Proxy'ing. And before you say "ask the vendor", there's a reason why I'm asking the internet....
